# MVC3 Html.RadioButton statpost back to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have the following model in my mvc3 application. I want to have two radio buttons on the view that map to Weight and Quantity (these are bit fields in the database).

```
public Unit()
    {
        this.OrderLineQuantity = new HashSet<OrderLine>();
        this.OrderLineWeight = new HashSet<OrderLine>();
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public System.Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public string ShortDescription { get; set; }
    public string Desciption { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime AddDate { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime UpdateDate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> Weight { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> Quantity { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<OrderLine> OrderLineQuantity { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<OrderLine> OrderLineWeight { get; set; }
```

I have the (simplified) following in my strongly typed razor view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<fieldset>
    <legend>Unit</legend>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Weight)</td>
            <td>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Quantity)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.RadioButton("unitType", "false", "Weight")
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Weight)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.RadioButton("unitType", "false", "Quantity")
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Quantity)
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
```

}

The issue I am having is when I debug the post back to the controller the values for the radio buttons are null. I'm a bit confused as I think I have named the controls correctly in the view. Can someone please help me get the values posting back to the controller correctly. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `RadioButtonFor`, that will wire up the form naming correctly.

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Weight, "true")
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Quantity, "true")
```

(If you wanted to use plain `RadioButton`, the first parameter should be the property name, like `@Html.RadioButton("Weight", "true")`.  But if gets more complex in the cases like nested classes and partial views, which is why it's advisable to use the strongly typed form as above.)

---

**Edit**  Since the radio buttons need to be in the same group, the view model has to be tweaked.

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.UnitType, "Weight")
@Html.RadioButton(model => model.UnitType, "Quantity")
```

So the model needs the `UnitType` property, but if you still need to use `Weight` and `Quantity`, then they could be set to update:

```
private string _unitType;

public string UnitType 
{
    get { return _unitType; }
    set
    {
        _unitType = value;
        Weight = (_unitType ?? "").Equals("Weight", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
        Quantity = (_unitType ?? "").Equals("Quantity", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but this does not put the radio buttons in the same group so when I select one I can also select the other. This is why I did not use the RadioButtonFor. Is there a way I can use the RadioButtonFor and but both in the same group?

Comment: @user1476207 sorry, totally missed that.  Updated my answer.